# 3d plot rgl index of matrix

Tags: r, matrix, rgl

I was hoping to create a 3D plot utilizing the `R` package `rgl`.  I was given the following code:

`plot3d(Z[,1], Z[,2], rep(0,300), type="s", radius=.1,
       col=rainbow(300)[rank(X[,1])])`

I believe `rep(0,300)` is where the problem is. In the data, I believe that column heading is not present. I believe `rep(0,300)` should be the `Z` portion of the 3D plot that I do not have.  I am getting a flat 3D plot. [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIjZ3.gif)

The data set is matrix with 3 columns: `Z1`, `Z2`, `Z3`.  I am wanting to plot `Z1`, `Z2`, and the "total number of records."

How do I reference the very far left column? I am referring the column that indicates the total number of records? 
[see dataset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHPWM.gif)

Comment: What is Z? While posting sample data is always a must, it's particularly important when you're working on a homework assignment, because homework help is highly triggering to many on Stackoverflow.

Comment: For this problem, I am doing principal component analysis. Z= X%*% U, X is the original set or data, and U is the rotation matrix of eigenvectors (I believe).  The original set of data X is 3 X 300 matrix. This is not homework, but it is a tutorial I am trying to follow.